# Android Instant App Deep Link Error - Provide exactly one URL

Tags: android, google-play, deep-linking

I am trying to create an instant app version of my game.

My main game has deep link (and/or app link, I really dont know the difference), and I want the instant app to have it also. By accessing http://mygame.mycompany.com/join?code=12345 , if the user has MyApp installed it will be launched and I will read the code parameter. This part is working fine. What I aim is for when the user doesnt have MyApp installed, I want the Instant App to be launched instead.

I followed all the docs I found but I keep getting the same error when I upload it to Google Play. I searched the error message on Google and found 0 hits, so that made me a bit nervous :)  I am contacting the Google Play support in the meantime, if I find a solution I will post here.

The error message is:

> "You must provide exactly one default URL for your Instant App APKs."

Does anyone know what that means?

I can upload my main app just fine, no error messages. The Instant App is the one that gives me the error message. And the deeplink is working fine in the main app.

My main app AndroidManifest.xml (relevant parts):

```
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mygame.mycompany.com" android:pathPattern="/join" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="mygame" />
      </intent-filter>
```

My instant app AndroidManifest.xml (relevant parts):

```
      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="mygame.mycompany.com" android:pathPattern="/join" />
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
      </intent-filter>
```

Thanks

Comment: instant app is already installed in user device?

Comment: That error is when I upload the instant app to Google Play Dev Console (using my computer), nothing to do with the device or anything.